# overloaded "=" equality does not get called when making obj2 = obj1 

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

i have this class called  MemoryManager,

it is supposed to implement a simple smart pointer, (count reference);
i have a vector where i store the requested pointers,and i return the index of the pointer to the caller..

when a user creates a pointer of type MemoryManager he calls an initializer function called modified_malloc(size_t) , create a MemoryManager obj, alloc a memory space and store it into data,increase count, and store the object into global_MM_vecotr , and return the index as a pointer , when the use tries to use indirection ( ->) i return the appropriate real pointer from the vector, according to the index value..

```
class MemoryManager
{
public:
    //operators overloading prototypes

private:
    void*  data;
    int count ;
};

 std::vector<MemoryManager*> global_MM_vecotr; 
  void* MemoryManager::operator=( void* x)
 {
   // some code here
 }
```

the problem i am facing is that i overloaded a couple of operators, however when i try to run the code below  the "=" operator doesn't get called.. 
can some1 point the problem out to me..

```
  //the main code 
 {

MemoryManager* obj1 = (MemoryManager*) x->fun1(4); //fun1 returns an index to a MemoryManager obj in a vector;
MemoryManager* obj2 =  obj1 ;
   }
```

Edit:     already tried the following , no change

```
  {  
        MemoryManager*obj1 = (MemoryManager*) x->fun1(4); //fun1 returns an index to a Class obj in a vector;
MemoryManager*obj2 ;
*obj2 =  *obj1;
  }


 {
     MemoryManager* obj1  = ( MemoryManager*) x-> fun1(4);
MemoryManager* obj2;
obj2.operator =(*obj1);
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From you code, you have defined `operator=` for the `MemoryManager` class taking a `void*` .

Your example code is initializing `ClassA` *pointers* and not assigning to `MemoryManager` instances.

There are three reasons why your code is not being called.

- You are initializing not assigning, so if anything a constructor would be called rather than an assignment operator.
- You are initializing pointers and not objects, pointers are basic types and you cannot provide overloaded operators for them.
- You are using `ClassA` and not `MemoryManager` which you have actually provided the `operator=` for.

Comment: i am sry about the misunderstading.. classA is the same as memorymanager.. i was in the process of renaming my "gibberish" names into more meanigful names.. when i posted the qus..

Comment: Fair enough, then you only need to address the other two points.

Comment: i edited the codes .. and omitted the use of ClassA :) , i moved the equality to after i created the object.
can u check the edited description and tell me what can i do to avoid using pointers :S

Comment: You are using lots of pointers, if you don't want to use them, stop using them! Perhaps you should post the full definition of `MemoryManager` and an explanation of what it's trying to achieve? With the small snippets with a slew of pointers and casts it's not easy to see what you are trying to do.

Comment: my friend, thx alot for ur clearification, after much thought..i am re-constructing the whole project using templates instead of class/void* .. again thx alot for ur help

Answer (score 4):

See spec, you cannot override pointer basic operations.

Comment: You should beef this answer up a bit, it's the correct one, but hard to understand.

Comment: @Konrad - I would like to cite Stroustrup, but unfortunately have only Russian version.

Answer (score 2):

Might be a technicality, but you're not assigning a `ClassA`, you're assigning a `ClassA*` (ie, a pointer). I might be way off here, but this is where I'd lay the blame.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you're using the void pointer so that you can enter any kind of object. I'd recommend using a [template](http://cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/templates/) instead combined with the [boost::check library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/libs/concept_check/concept_check.htm).